# Disabling/Enabling Jquery onClick Functions

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to 'disable' or 'suspend' a jquery .click function, without unbinding? I want to leave the function bound, but don't want it to fire. Then, at a later time, I would like to re-enable it.

Just disabling the control being bound to will not suffice in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a flag in a higher variable scope and only execute the handler if the flag is on. Here's a simple example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var execHandler = false;
    $('input').click(function (e) {
        if (execHandler) {
            //do stuff
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
    $('button#toggleHandler').click(function (e) {
        execHandler = !execHandler;
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    })
});
```

It's a similiar solution to: [Suppress jQuery event handling temporarily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809275/suppress-jquery-event-handling-temporarily)

Comment: Great suggestion! Worked perfectly.