# Onclick "li" enable and disable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using:

```
$('#btnEmpresarial').attr('onclick','').unbind('click');
```

To disable a `read` by javascript..

Now I needed to activate the `onclick` after the end of the function.

Does anyone know to disable and enable the `onclick` of a `li`?

Comment: Alguém sabe desabilitar e habilitar o "onclick" de um "li"?  what does it  mean ?

Comment: The code before doesn't make sense either. But [the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) should show an error.

Comment: I don't speak Italian (Spanish?) but I think it means "Does anyone know how to disable the behaviour of `onclick` on the li"

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester I speak Italian, that's not Italian...

Comment: You should really formulate your questions a bit better. I speak semi-fluent drunkanese and jibberish, but I have clue what you're asking...

Comment: Google says its portuguese https://translate.google.com/?rlz=1C1CHMO_enUS532US532&q=Algu%C3%A9m+sabe+desabilitar+e+habilitar+o&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45960087,d.Yms&biw=1600&bih=762&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&sa=N&tab=wT#auto/en/Algu%C3%A9m%20sabe%20desabilitar%20e%20habilitar%20o%22onclick%22%20de%20um%20%22li%22

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling/Enabling Jquery onClick Functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054821/disabling-enabling-jquery-onclick-functions)

Comment: it is brasilian portuguese btw

Comment: Sorry! I am newbie in stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do:

```
$('li.something').unbind('click'); // to disable
```

To enable you need to rebind the function

```
$('li.something').bind('click', function() { ...
```

---

I don't know what you want to do, but if you actually want to unbind/bind the event like an (on/off) then you should store the function and just pass it in the bind.

Like:

```
function foo(){ ... }

$('li.something').unbind('click'); // to disable
$('li.something').bind('click', foo);
```

Comment: I'm doing an animation, and do not want to leave the User keep clicking the buttons several times