# jQuery selectmenu - multiple menus, reset value of others when one is changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, select-menu

I am using the selectmenu plugin to style up some select menus on my site. I am using them for a filtering feature on my site. I want the user to only be able to filter by one menu at a time. So when a user selects an option on one menu the value on the other menu needs to go back to the default option.

I have a jsfiddle set up of what I'm trying to accomplish. It is almost working. I can get other menu to reset its value back to the first value in the list of options. The problem is the one I am changing does not change, it just stays at its default value.

Hopefully I've explained this well enough. Here's the link to the jsfiddle....

http://jsfiddle.net/dmcgrew/FBzFL/

Here's my code:

```
<select name="type" id="type">
<option value="*" selected="selected">Select Project Type</option>
<option value=".annualreport">Annual Report</option>
<option value=".branding">Branding</option> 
<option value=".brochures">Brochures</option>
<option value=".retail-signage">Retail Signage</option>
<option value=".video">Video</option>
<option value=".web">Web Development</option>       
</select>

<select name="industry" id="industry">
<option value="*" selected="selected" class="default">Select Project Industry</option>
<option value=".consumergoods">Consumer Goods</option>
<option value=".education">Education</option>
<option value=".entertainment">Entertainment</option>
<option value=".food">Food</option>
<option value=".healthcare">Healthcare</option>
</select>

$(function(){            


$('select').selectmenu({
menuWidth: 170,
width: 170,
maxHeight: 600
});

$('select#type').change(function(){
$("select#industry").selectmenu("index", 0);
});

$('select#industry').change(function(){
$("select#type").selectmenu("index", 0);
});



});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, figured it out!

When you change the value of one select drop-down programmatically, it'll fire any change listeners attached to the element.  So even if you change the value of one select drop-down through the UI, both change listeners will end up being fired.

**EDIT**: Glad to hear you figured it out! Yes, I was trying to figure out a way to retain the change listeners, but it's much more difficult than I thought it would be, unless I'm missing something obvious.  But setting up click listeners on the anchor elements should solve this problem nicely.

Comment: I think I have it figured out. I'm detecting a click on the <a> instead of a change on the <select>.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to detect a `click()` on the `a` within the dropdown instead of a `change()` on the `select`. Here's the new js:

```
$('ul#type-menu li a').click(function(){
    $("select#industry").selectmenu("index", 0);
});

$('ul#industry-menu li a').click(function(){
    $("select#type").selectmenu("index", 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unbind the listeners but a better solution in my opinion is to add and remove a class instead (see [Suppress jQuery event handling temporarily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809275/suppress-jquery-event-handling-temporarily)). In your case:

```
$('select#type').change(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('fired') == false) {
        $('select#type').addClass('fired');
        $('select#industry').selectmenu("index", 0);
    }
    $('select#industry').removeClass('fired');    
});

$('select#industry').change(function(){
     if ($(this).hasClass('fired') == false) {
        $('select#industry').addClass('fired');
        $("select#type").selectmenu("index", 0);
    }
    $('select#type').removeClass('fired');   
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JEfMD/