# On/off click event on alternating tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#filter').on('click', function(){
    $('#sort').off('click');
    console.log($(this));
});

$('#sort').on('click', function(){
    $('#filter').off('click');
    console.log($(this))
});

$('.close').on('click', function () {
    console.log($(this));
    $('#sort').on('click');
    $('#filter').on('click');
});
```

Why doesnt the div `.close` give back the on method to the divs above if they have the same selector id?

EDIT: For clarity, I'm wanting to temporarily remove the on event on whichever of the two elements **wasn't** clicked (`#filter` or `#sort`). Then clicking `'.close'` will return the said element back to having the on method again.

Comment: @DhavalMarthak You might as well be concise and just use `$(selector).click()`

Comment: @Luxelin Yup.. that also can be used! :)

Comment: Someone actually wrote a jQuery plugin for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809275/suppress-jquery-event-handling-temporarily).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `off()` does not work the way you think. It actually removes the event handlers (callback functions), not just hides them, so you cannot restore them with a simple `on()`, they are not stored any longer by the element after the `off()`, you have to add them again. It is not easy to track whether an event handler is added, so I suggest another approach.

```
var sort = true;
var filter = true;

$('#filter').on('click', function(){
    if (!filter)
        return;
    sort = false;
    console.log($(this));
});

$('#sort').on('click', function(){
    if (!sort)
        return;
    filter = false;
    console.log($(this))
});

$('.close').on('click', function () {
    console.log($(this));
    sort = true;
    filter = true;
});
```

Another approach to use `toggle()` and combine it with the `on()` and `off()` functions. Hmm I found that jquery `toggle()` is not loosely coupled to dom elements, so you cannot do this with that. You have to create your own implementation, for example something like this:

```
function toggle(options) {
    var currentValue = !!options.value;
    return function (value){
        if (value === undefined)
            value = !currentValue;
        if (value != currentValue)
            if (value) {
                currentValue = true;
                options.on();
            }
            else {
                currentValue = false;
                options.off();
            }
    };
}
```

With this toggle implementation your code will be the following:

```
var switches = {
    sort: toggle({
        on: function (){
            $('#sort').on('click', function(){
                switches.filter(false);
                console.log($(this))
            });
        },
        off: function (){
            $('#sort').off('click');
        }
    }),
    filter: toggle({
        on: function (){
            $('#filter').on('click', function(){
                switches.sort(false);
                console.log($(this));
            });
        },
        off: function (){
            $('#filter').off('click');
        }
    })
};

$('.close').on('click', function () {
    console.log($(this));
    switches.sort(true);
    switches.filter(true);
});

switches.sort(true);
switches.filter(true);
```

Comment: Great, thanks for your thorough input! The top one works well, will try the latter OO version now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
$('#filter:not(.off)').on('click', function(){
    $('#sort').addClass('off');
    console.log($(this));
});

$('#sort:not(.off)').on('click', function(){
    $('#filter').addClass('off');
    console.log($(this))
});

$('.close').on('click', function(){
    $('#sort').removeClass('off');
    $('#filter').removeClass('off');
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that in your block of code…

```
$('.close').on('click', function () {
    console.log($(this));
    $('#sort').on('click');
    $('#filter').on('click');
});
```

You want to click `#sort` and `#filter`. To do such, you'll need to do the following:

```
$('.close').on('click', function () {
    console.log($(this));
    $('#sort').click();
    $('#filter').click();
});
```

Even so, it would probably be better to wrap the other event handlers in a function and call them like such:

```
$('.close').on('click', function () {
    console.log($(this));
    sortClickFunction();
    filterClickFunction();
});
```

Comment: Maybe its my bad way of explaining this particular request..i dont want '.close' to initiate a click for the sort or filter, i want it to return the on method back to either sort or filter (depending which has been removed from the first 2 blocks)

Comment: @lxm7 Are you saying that you want to remove the event handlers temporarily?

Comment: Yeah, when one is selected (filter or sort), the other unclicked one temporarily has the on method removed until the '.close' clicked gives it back to said element thats had it removed. I'll add this to the question for clarity. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This will do anything:      `$('#sort').on('click');`

You need to call: `$('#sort').trigger('click');`

Comment: He's removed the event handler.  He's trying to add it back, not trigger it.

Comment: Thank you, didn't catch that.