# Jquery remove and add back click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to remove than add back click event to specific element? i.e

I have a <strike>`$("#elem").click(function{//some behaviour});`,</strike> `$(".elem").click(function{//some behaviour});`(there are more than 1 element) while my other function `getJson` is executing I'd like to remove the click event from the `#elem`, and add it again onsuccess from getJson function, but preserve both mouseenter and mouseleave events the whole time?

Or maybe create overlay to prevent clicking like in modal windows? is that better idea?

**edit :**

I've seen some really good answers, but there is one detail that I omitted not on purpose. There are more than one element, and I call the click function on the className not on elementId as I stated in the original question

Comment: An initial if-statement inside the event handler might check whether a boolean `jsonIsLoaded` is true or not. If it is, then set it to `false` and continue, otherwise you call `event.preventDefault()` and return false. That way you don't have to bind and unbind events all the time!

Comment: `function` must be followed by a set of parentheses, optionally receiving the click event as a parameter: `function(evt){ ... }`. Regarding your update: should _all_ elements be unclickable, or just the one clicked?

Comment: @afEkenholm tnx for your feedback, only the one being clicked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than using [unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/), which means you'll have to rebind the same event handler later, you can use jQuery's [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) facility with the [ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) events to have your elements ignore `click` events during all AJAX requests:

```
$(".elem").click(function() {
    if (!$(this).data("ajaxRequestPending")) {
        // some behaviour
    }
}).ajaxStart(function() {
    $(this).data("ajaxRequestPending", true);
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    $(this).removeData("ajaxRequestPending");
});
```

**EDIT:** This answer is also *id-to-class-proof* (see questioner's edit), since everything matching the selector will handle the AJAX events the right way. That's the main selling point of jQuery, and it shows.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi but I'm not using ajax function, I'm using getJson also from jquery, or does it also belongs as ajax function?

Comment: @London, [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) calls [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) internally, so it actually *is* an AJAX function, and triggers `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` as expected.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi absolutely simple,amazing, briliant

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi one more thing, it works exactly as I wanted

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/).  Pass it `'click'` and it will destroy the click event.

I would put it just before your `getJSON` and re-bind the click event inside the success handler of your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some additional scripting. There is no callback for that. Take a look over here: [jQuery - How can I temporarily disable the onclick event listener after the event has been fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921855/jquery-how-can-i-temporarily-disable-the-onclick-event-listener-after-the-event/1922121#1922121)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than unbinding/binding the click event, you could check the state of another variable to see if it should do the action.

```
var MyObject = {
  requestActive = false;
};

function MyJsonFunction() {
  // when requesting
  MyObject.requestActive = true;
  //...
  // when request over
  MyObject.requestActive = false;

}

$("#elem").click(function{
  if (MyObject.requestActive == true) {
    //do something
  }
});
```