# stop .net form submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I stop the form from submitting as the below does not work on my .net form as the button already has a in-line click event. How do I make the event below override every other function on the button.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myBtn').click(function (event) {

        //event.preventDefault();

        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: What is the above code aiming to acheive? By triggering a click event on '#myButton' you will be firing the in-line event on it.

Comment: your question is very similar to another thread, please search before posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921855/jquery-how-can-i-temporarily-disable-the-onclick-event-listener-after-the-even

Comment: not yet           ........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you'd just use [**submit()**](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) instead of `click()`:

```
$('#form').submit(function (event) {    
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$('#myBtn').onclick = null;
$('#myBtn').click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using master pages you must call the client id instead of actual ID,.

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#<%=myBtn.ClientID%>').click(function () {   
        return false;
    });    
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried on ASP side?

```
<asp:Button ID="myBtn" UseSubmitBehavior="false"></asp:Button>
```

Or overriding the submit event of the form via jQuery?

```
$("form").submit(function(e) { return false; });
```

If this behaviour is not the intended (because you have other buttons to post), try one of these:

```
$("#myBtn").removeAttr("onclick");
$("#myBtn").attr("onclick", "return false;");
$("#myBtn").off("click");
$("#myBtn").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

Then you can bind your own click event on it.