# Disable Onclick until end of duration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a jquery plugin [jrumble](http://jackrugile.com/jrumble/) so I can achieve a shake effect on my div. On the function **onclick** the shake effect will run, and after some time, an alert will popup, the alert contains typical responses from the magic eight ball. However, If I click the div multiple times quickly, the div will shake continuously, and an alert will popup multiple times consecutively. I want to disable the onclick until the alert popup is shown. Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jrumble.1.3.min.js"></script>

<div class="middleBall">
<div id="MagicEightBall"><img src="ball01.png" width="100%"> </div>
</div>

<script>
var messages = new Array();
messages[0] = "No";
messages[1] = "Not today";
messages[2] = "It is decidedly so";
messages[3] = "Without a doubt";
messages[4] = "Yes definitely";
messages[5] = "You may rely on it";
messages[6] = "As I see it yes";
messages[7] = "Most likely";
messages[8] = "Outlook good";
messages[10] = "Signs point to yes";
messages[11] = "Reply hazy try again";
messages[12] = "Ask again later";
messages[13] = "Better not tell you now";
messages[14] = "Cannot predict now";
messages[15] = "Concentrate and ask again";
messages[16] = "Don't count on it";
messages[17] = "My reply is no";
messages[18] = "My sources say no";
messages[19] = "Outlook not so good";
messages[20] = "Very doubtful";


$('#MagicEightBall').jrumble({
x: 10,
y: 10,
rotation: 3,
speed: -100
});
var demoTimeout;
var answerTimeout;
$('#MagicEightBall').click(function(){
$this = $(this);
clearTimeout(demoTimeout);
clearTimeout(answerTimeout);
$this.trigger('startRumble');
demoTimeout = setTimeout(function(){$this.trigger('stopRumble');}, 3000)
finishFast = setTimeout (function(){
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
alert(messages[randomnumber]);
},3500);

});
</script>
```

Comment: use one event in jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **<kbd>[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jDDCg/)</kbd>**

***jQuery Code***

```
$('#MagicEightBall').click(function(){
    var handler = arguments.callee;
    $this = $(this);
    $this.off("click", handler);
    clearTimeout(demoTimeout);
    clearTimeout(answerTimeout);
    $this.trigger('startRumble');
    demoTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        $this.trigger('stopRumble');
        $this.click(handler);
    }, 3000)
    finishFast = setTimeout(function () {
        var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
        alert(messages[randomnumber]);
    }, 3500);
});
```

[Reference Help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1922012/2260614)

Answer (score 1):

Folks try this i have made some modifications.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jrumble.1.3.min.js"></script>

<div class="middleBall">
<div id="MagicEightBall"><img src="ball01.png" width="100%"> </div>
</div>

<script>
var messages = new Array();
messages[0] = "No";
messages[1] = "Not today";
messages[2] = "It is decidedly so";
messages[3] = "Without a doubt";
messages[4] = "Yes definitely";
messages[5] = "You may rely on it";
messages[6] = "As I see it yes";
messages[7] = "Most likely";
messages[8] = "Outlook good";
messages[10] = "Signs point to yes";
messages[11] = "Reply hazy try again";
messages[12] = "Ask again later";
messages[13] = "Better not tell you now";
messages[14] = "Cannot predict now";
messages[15] = "Concentrate and ask again";
messages[16] = "Don't count on it";
messages[17] = "My reply is no";
messages[18] = "My sources say no";
messages[19] = "Outlook not so good";
messages[20] = "Very doubtful";


$('#MagicEightBall').jrumble({
x: 10,
y: 10,
rotation: 3,
speed: -100
});
var demoTimeout;
var answerTimeout;
$('#MagicEightBall').click(function(){
$this = $(this);

clearTimeout(demoTimeout);
clearTimeout(answerTimeout);
$this.trigger('startRumble');
$this.css("pointer-events","none");
demoTimeout = setTimeout(function(){$this.trigger('stopRumble'); $this.attr("disabled",false);}, 3000)
finishFast = setTimeout (function(){
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
alert(messages[randomnumber]);
 $this.css("pointer-events","auto");
},3500);

});
</script>
```

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to set a variable "rumbling" to 1 when the shaking starts and clearing it when it finishes.

Then modify the click event so that it does nothing if the variable is set.