# Queue up a function after click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a problem with queuing up events in jQuery. I have an elevator project that allows the user to click on buttons, and then lights go on and then numbers change. That works fine, except when they punch a number again before it reaches the floor picked the first time. I want it to get to the floor first picked before it goes to the second clicked floor (or third, or fourth, etc.). I've done some stuff with `.promise`, when done, etc. and none of it seems to work.

I am using `.click` which appears to be the issue, because it fires the function regardless of where it is currently. Trouble is that I can't seem to find any alternative and it needs to finish current operation first before moving on to any other floors.

I hope I explained this well. If not please let me know. Perhaps there is another way entirely of doing it. Still learning this front end/jQuery stuff.

```
$( ".button" ).click(function(event) {      
    // doing stuff here....
    $( runMainscript() ).promise().done(function() {
        runMainscript(buttonclicked, floorQ);
    });

});

function runMainscript(buttonclicked,floorQ) {
    //doing stuff here
}
```

BTW, here is a timer for 2 seconds on each floor.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ak25Lxab/1/

See how if you click on two buttons quickly, it jumps around?

Comment: It's not easy to understand all the details, some simple jsfiddle would really help.

Comment: Are you sure this is the right fiddle? Where is elevator and other stuff?

Comment: I see "Hello world" text and nothing more, no panels

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ak25Lxab/1/ Try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object works slightly differently. You should explicitly declare a deferred variable like this:

```
var dfd = new $.Deferred();
```

And when you want to fire `done` callback, you should call:

```
dfd.resolve();
```

So your queueing part of the script now looks like this:

```
$.when(dfd.promise()).done(function() {
    dfd = new $.Deferred();
    var onfloor = $("#onfloor").text();
    runMainscript(buttonclicked, floorQ, onfloor);
});
```

And inside `runMainscript` you resolve this `dfd` deferred when elevator arrived to the floor.
See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zr28dpn2/). Now, all floors are in the queue using deferred object.

I'm not an expert in deferreds, so maybe you can optimise this script further.

Comment: That is awesome. Thanks Ilya Luzyanin! I marked that as the answer. I experimented with deferred at one point, but I never got it to work.

Comment: You're welcome! Too bad you can't upvote - it's hard to gain reputation these days, trying hard to earn it...

Answer (score -1):

I don't really understand your problem and your jsfiddle is not working for me but as far as I can see you want to stop listen for the click event when the elevator is moving.

To do this you can stop listening for the click event and then restore the listener.
http://api.jquery.com/off/

So ideally, listen for the click event, as soon as it's fired stop listening for the click event, do your operations and then restore the listener on the click event for the `.button`

Or you can try to do something like this, put a state and do nothing if the state is not cleared:
[jQuery - How can I temporarily disable the onclick event listener after the event has been fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921855/jquery-how-can-i-temporarily-disable-the-onclick-event-listener-after-the-even)

Comment: My instructions were for the buttons to be available at all times, so stop listening for the click won't work. Basically it has to have a queue, so that everytime someone clicks, it is added to the queue, and then continues on. Thanks for your help oozic.

Comment: I thought I can create a psuedo-queue if I fire off the function one at time, let it run fully and then the next one would go. But I haven't been able to do that. It might take some reworking.