# How to prevent other click events from running while one of them is already running in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, click

I am writing a simple fade-slideshow with `previous` and `next` buttons.

The problem is that when I click the `next` button very quickly (for example 2 times), before the first event finished, the second one will be executed, so for less than a second I will see, two images in my page.

```
    $("#next_button").click(function (){
        $("#slide"+current_slide).fadeOut(FADE_DURATION, function () {
            current_slide ++;
            current_slide = current_slide % slides_number;
            $("#slide"+current_slide).fadeIn(FADE_DURATION, function (){
                $(".slide_image").not("#slide"+current_slide).attr("style", "display: none;");
            });
        });
    });
```

- In the last line, after `fadeIn()`, I even tried to hide everything except current image, wishing the issue will be solved, but that doesn't work.
- I read something about `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` but I couldn't use it, or maybe it wasn't my solution.

How to force `jQuery` to ignore executing any similar events, before one of those same events, get finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a flag that indicates when your slider is in the middle of transitioning:

```
var isSliding = false;

$("#next_button").click(function (){

  if(isSliding) {
    return false;
  }

  isSliding = true;

    $("#slide"+current_slide).fadeOut(FADE_DURATION, function () {
        current_slide ++;
        current_slide = current_slide % slides_number;
        $("#slide"+current_slide).fadeIn(FADE_DURATION, function (){
            $(".slide_image").not("#slide"+current_slide).attr("style", "display: none;");

            isSliding = false;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple! I thought it must be something complicated related to event handling, which I don't know anything about it. :)

Comment: You can accomplish this with binding/unbinding of events too, but it's a bit more complicated. As another answerer mentioned, you can check out those solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921855/jquery-how-can-i-temporarily-disable-the-onclick-event-listener-after-the-even

And if you want to learn more about event binding in jQuery you can read up about it in the jQuery API docs: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

You can bind and unbind, but it is time consumer if you repeat it a lot, if yo neet to fo it more than few times try to look into this answer: [jQuery - How can I temporarily disable the onclick event listener after the event has been fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921855/jquery-how-can-i-temporarily-disable-the-onclick-event-listener-after-the-even)