# How to repeat onclick function synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function

```
function removecost(e,parent) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var current_Explanation = parent;
        var other_Explanations = current_Explanation.siblings('.repeatingcostsection');


        if (other_Explanations.length === 0) {
            alert("You should atleast have one Cost Section");
            return;
        }
        current_Explanation.slideUp('slow', function() {
            current_Explanation.remove();

            // reset Explanation indexes
            other_Explanations.each(function() {
               resetAttributeNames($(this));
            })

        })
}
```

The function doesn't do any special. It is called on a delete icon's onclick attribute and checks the number of siblings for `current_Explanation`. If they are greater than zero then it removes current_Explanation. If the siblings length is 0 then it alerts a message **"You should atleast have one Cost Section".**

The functionality works absolutely fine if the user clicks slowly on the icon. But if user clicks clicks continuously very fast on the icon, the alert message is not shown and all blocks are removed because

> I think
>
> ```
> other_Explanations.each(function() {
>                resetAttributeNames($(this));
>             });
> ```
>
> is not completed properly.

Comment: alerts are not reliable. In Chrome I can suppress them easily. Think about using a dialog instead.

Answer (score 0):

you need to disable the button till the whole processing is done

```
function removecost(e,parent) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $(e.target).prop('disabled', true); //disable it here


        var current_Explanation = parent;
        var other_Explanations = current_Explanation.siblings('.repeatingcostsection');


        if (other_Explanations.length === 0) {
            alert("You should atleast have one Cost Section");
            return;
        }
        current_Explanation.slideUp('slow', function() {
            current_Explanation.remove();

            // reset Explanation indexes
            other_Explanations.each(function() {
               resetAttributeNames($(this));
            })

           $(e.target).prop('disabled', false); //enable it again
        })
}
```

Note that you need to enable it once the slide up is complete.

Comment: I wanted to have some other solution instead of disabling it. By the way disabling the target is not working.

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com any specific reason for that? Did I missed any limitation you had posted in your question itself?

Comment: Are you really sure, that disabling a dom element will also disable the click event also?

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com if it is not a form input element then it wont work since disabled property is for input elements. you can still disable click event temporarily using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921855/jquery-how-can-i-temporarily-disable-the-onclick-event-listener-after-the-even

Answer (score 0):

you need a debounce function or throttle function, which could throttle the amount of times your codes runs.

here is an example:

```
 function throttle(fn, threshhold, scope) {
        threshhold || (threshhold = 250);
        var last,
            deferTimer;
        return function () {
            var context = scope || this;

            var now = +new Date,
                args = arguments;
            if (last && now < last + threshhold) {//last execute time
                // store timer
                clearTimeout(deferTimer);
                deferTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                    last = now;
                    fn.apply(context, args);
                }, threshhold);
            } else {
                last = now;
                fn.apply(context, args);//after Nth , have to wait threshhold to execute(N+1)th time.
            }
        };
    }
```

you can use it in this way:

```
  $btn.on('click',throttle(function(){
      //your codes
  },300));
```

and this means your codes will be execute only once during 300ms

you can also using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) to achieve same effect