# Javascript Bind and Unbind function call

Tags: jquery

I have this following code in in jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('Hello');

    var uploadButton = $('#upload-button');

    uploadButton.on('click', function () {
        uploadButton.unbind('click');
        progressBar();
        uploadButton.bind('click');
    });

});

function progressBar(){

    var element = document.getElementById('bar');
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(addFrame, 25);

    function addFrame() {
        if(width == 100){
            clearInterval(id);

            element.style.width = 0;
            return true;
        }

        width += 1;
        element.style.width = width + '%';
    }

}
```

What I'm trying to do is to call a function for a progress bat when an HTML `button` item is being pressed, but also try to disable anymore calls until the current call is finished. By initial idea was to unbind the `click` event when it is being pressed, execute the function, and then bind `click` again to the same element, but so far, the only thing I get is only one call of `progressBar` and after that, the `button` remains unbound for `click`.
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Look here for examples on how you can remove the click event temporarily: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921855/jquery-how-can-i-temporarily-disable-the-onclick-event-listener-after-the-even

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the unbind method, this method don't put the event in on/off, else that it removes the function associated to the button, the unbind isn't the way to resolve that. 
For temporary removes click event i recommend to do this:

- disable the HTML button using `$('#myButton').prop('disabled', true)`
- and enable that, after in a callback function of the progressbar function using `$('#myButton').prop('disabled', false)`

I hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on my own, using `prop`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('Hello');

    var uploadButton = $('#upload-button');

    uploadButton.on('click', function () {
        console.log('clicked');
        progressBar(uploadButton);
    });

});

function progressBar(target){

    target.prop('disabled', true);

    var element = document.getElementById('bar');
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(addFrame, 25);

    function addFrame() {
        if(width == 99){
            clearInterval(id);
            element.style.width = 0 + '%';

            target.prop('disabled', false);
        }

        //make it to display actual file upload

        width += 1;
        element.style.width = width + '%';
    }
}
```

Passing the object as parameter, I managed to disable it, make my operations, and enable it after that. Might work with other attributes as well.