# Stop a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a `ResetTime` function implemented that I need to stop once a modal is being called. The `ResetTime` function is being used for a session timeout. Everytime there is user interaction the time gets reset.

`ResetTime` function

```
function ResetTime() {
    timer = SetLastResetTimeStamp((new Date()).getTime());
} 

function SetLastResetTimeStamp(timeStamp) {
    if (_localStorage) {
        _localStorage[_localStorageKey] = timeStamp;
    } else {
        _lastResetTimeStamp = timeStamp;
    }
}
```

User Interaction checks:

```
AttachEvent(document, 'click', ResetTime);
AttachEvent(document, 'mousemove', ResetTime);
AttachEvent(document, 'keypress', ResetTime);
AttachEvent(window, 'load', ResetTime);
```

Is there a way to stop the `ResetTime` function in another function?

Comment: `if(modal is open) return;`

Comment: just like in real life, you set a condition. in real life: `if driving -> don't hold phone` and so in code it's only logical to set up conditions as well. you need to use `if` statement, and then set the condition for which the function should be called in the first place, or if the condition cannot be set there then you should set it within the function itself, like @Phiter wrote above.

Comment: Maybe the solution will be to logging time when modal is open, and change the business logic somehow. Otherwise, a solution will be declaring a global variable (instead is worst, because polluting global namespace), then if(modalIsOpen){myGlobVar=true}. In SetLastResetTimeStamp check myGlobVar, if false do localstorage stuff, else return. In this way you don't need to detach-reattach the events. Is just an idea ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution suggested by @Phiter would work, i.e. you can define `ResetTime` in a scope containing a flag `modalIsOpen` and then define it as follows:

```
function ResetTime() {
  if (modalIsOpen) {
    return;
  }

  timer = SetLastResetTimeStamp((new Date()).getTime());
}
```

However, I think it would be cleaner to detach the events when your modal is opened and reattach them when it's getting closed. This will stop the function from getting called in the first place. I.e. assuming you have two functions `onModalOpen` and `onModalClose` and a `DetachEvent` function which removes events from the respective `EventTarget`s:

```
const onModalOpen = () => {
    DetachEvent(document, 'click', ResetTime);
    DetachEvent(document, 'mousemove', ResetTime);
    DetachEvent(document, 'keypress', ResetTime);
    DetachEvent(window, 'load', ResetTime);

    // ...
}

const onModalClose = () => {
    AttachEvent(document, 'click', ResetTime);
    AttachEvent(document, 'mousemove', ResetTime);
    AttachEvent(document, 'keypress', ResetTime);
    AttachEvent(window, 'load', ResetTime);

    // ...
}
```

---

**NOTE:** Unbinding and rebinding event handlers is not uncontroversial though (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1921909/305949)).

As a sidenote, you cannot **stop** functions in JavaScript (or in most programming languages). You can only stop them from being executed (e.g. by returning early, throwing errors or simply not calling them in the first place.)