# How to disable a click event for some time using jquery?

Tags: javascript, events, jquery, click

I have a left tree. Its structure is like this

```
    MainCategory
      Category1
        Subcategory1
        Subcategory2
      Category2
        Subcategory3
        Subcategory4
        Subcategory5
      Category3
      .
      .. etc like that
```

If user click any of the MainCategory/Category/Subcategory I need to disable/prevent repeated/multiple click on same link until the result come. How can I do that using jquery?

Comment: Can you include the jQuery you use to bind / attach to the click event ?

Comment: Been answered before -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263042/how-to-temporarily-disable-a-click-handler-in-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use jQuery 1.7 you can use the [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) and [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) functionality

example:

```
var foo = function () {
    // code to handle some kind of event
};

// ... now foo will be called when paragraphs are clicked ...
$("body").on("click", "p", foo);


// ... foo will no longer be called.
$("body").off("click", "p", foo);
```

if you use an older version you could [unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) and [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) the event

example:

```
var foo = function () {
    // code to handle some kind of event
};

// ... now foo will be called when paragraphs are clicked ...
$("body p").bind("click", foo);

// ... foo will no longer be called.
$("body p").unbind("click");
```

Answer (score 1):

May be just use a class to check if its already clicked.
If clicked, do not execute, and remove the class on success and failure.

Prototype -

```
$('.selector').click(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('someclass')){
        $(this).addClass('someclass');
        $.ajax({
          url: "test.html",
          success: function(){
            $(this).removeClass("someclass");
          },
          error: function(){
            $(this).removeClass("someclass");
          }
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: this doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/manuel/XcYqJ/ event is already binded and doesn't check if the class is present or not

Comment: The check for the class is within the click event. So it does not prevent the click. but simply does not execute what is within the click. Please check the code.

Comment: sorry! my bad. however isn't beter to use the live event for this? then you don't have to check it by you're self if the class is set. once again sorry for not reading your code well enough :)

Comment: np :) ... Live would be if the elements are added dynamically. binding/unbinding or on/off as you suggested would be a good option.