# How to prevent too frequent request in Ajax

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

I'm using a jQuery to submit the data from form to my controller file.

It is adding a favourite piece to the database, but, how to prevent user from sending the data trought ajax script too frequent?

I mean, I can click on the submit button in my form thousand amount of times - how to prevent that? So it will be for example, 1 request per 10 seconds?

Comment: You would have to prevent that in the file being called, because what AJAX does is just a simple request, which you could also call by typing in the URL in the address bar. You could do a simple IP or cookie check in the file being called.

Comment: You could disable the button when they click it, and when you receive your AJAX response add a delay callback function to reenable it.

Comment: @Andy Could you post an example with how it should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just off the top of my head I would say something like this:

```
$("#button_id").one('click', DoSomething);    // attaches the function for ONE click

function DoSomething() {
    $.post("test.php", function(data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        $("#button_id").delay(10000).one('click', DoSomething);   // reattach the listener 
    });        
}
```

Source copied from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263042/how-to-temporarily-disable-a-click-handler-in-jquery) and the [jQuery manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)