# jQuery unbind click event function and re-attach depending on situation

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, binding, click

The code below I use to create a sliding menu. I need to know how to unbind the function attached to the click event and re-attach it some other time. (using jQuery 1.7.2)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.section').hide();
    $('.header').click(function(){
      if($(this).next('.section').is(':visible'))
      {
        $('.section:visible').slideUp()              
        $('.arrows:visible').attr("src","right.gif")
      }
      else
      {
        $('.section').slideUp();
        $(this).next('.section').slideToggle();
        $(this).find('.arrows').attr("src","down.gif")
    });
});
```

The code below is what I have so far

```
$('#printVers').click(function(){
   if($('#formVersion').val() != "Print")
   {
     $('.header').unbind('click');
   }
   else
   {
     //else re-attach functionality?
   }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: So you simply want to take the click event handler for `$('.header')` on or off based on some formVersion value?

Comment: Well yes, but how do i refer to the click function in the first code block to re-attach it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to temporarily disable a click handler in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263042/how-to-temporarily-disable-a-click-handler-in-jquery)

Comment: Maybe i should try and re-engage my brain with coffee and food rather than ask silly questions on a Friday afternoon, not only was it a silly question but one that has already been asked :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply make a named function. You can go low tech here and back to basics to unbind and reattach specific events.

```
function doStuff()
{
    if($(this).,next('.section').is(':visible'))
        ...
}

$('.header').on('click', doStuff);
$('.header').off('click', doStuff);
```

Comment: Damn, you beat me by 30 seconds XD

Comment: It's so simple it's not even funny. Thanks Tejs

Comment: It would be nice to be able to get a handle of the last bound function without having to use the fn name. Like `elem.on('click', myfn)`. Then somewhere else completely unrelated we could have `var fn = elem.lastClickHandler()`, `elem.off('click', fn)`, `// some code without handler`, `elem.on('click', fn)`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of unbind and re-bind, I suggest you to add a simple class to `.header` and check for the class in the click handler. See below,

```
$('#printVers').click(function(){
   if($('#formVersion').val() != "Print")
   {
     $('.header').addClass('dontClick');
   } else  {
     $('.header').removeClass('dontClick');
   }
});
```

And in your `.header` click handler,

```
$('.header').click(function(){
     if ($(this).hasClass('dontClick')) {
        return false;
     }
     //rest of your code
```

If you insist on having a unbind and bind, then you can move the handler to a function and unbind/bind the function any number of time..

Comment: Thanks i also like this version, again something i hadn't thought of doing.

Comment: @MarkWalters bind/unbinding a event handler is lot of work than simply adding and removing a class. This is a common technique, but again it is up to you to choose which method you want to follow.

Comment: How is Tjes idea of using `.on()` and `.off()` and naming the function a lot of hassle? I like both ideas and i did upvote your answer! :)

Comment: @MarkWalters upvote doesn't matter.. I was just saying that bind/rebind an event handler is expensive than adding a class and removing a class.

Comment: What do you mean by expensive? because you said it was a lot of work before, to which i disagree i actually think for me to implement (although minimal) there is slightly more to do with your code?

Comment: @MarkWalters expensive is not always lengthy code. Check out this simple jsPerformance comparision >> http://jsperf.com/bind-rebind-vs-addclass-removeclass << -> $.noop is an empty function. Again, I am just giving you a suggestion and not trying to force you to follow any specific implementation.

Comment: I know you aren't trying to force me, Thank you for the explanation i will take a look at that link. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
$('#printVers').click(function(){
   if($('#formVersion').val() != "Print")
   {
       $('.header').addClass('clickDisabled');
   }
   else
   {
       $('.header').removeClass('clickDisabled');
   }
});
```

And then in the click handler check for this class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.section').hide();
    $('.header').click(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('clickDisabled')){
            ...
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Guess our recommendation is not considered :)

Comment: Hmmmm...there are different ways to do it...but our thoughts match :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not make that top section a function, and then call it in your else statement?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting a variable as a flag. `var canClick = ($('#formVersion').val() != 'Print');` Then in the click handler for your `.header` elements check to see if `canClick` is true before executing your code.

If you still want to remove the handler you can assign the events object to a variable. `var eventObj = #('.header').data('events');` That will give you an object with all the handlers assigned to that object. To reassign the click event it would be like `$('.header').bind('click', eventObj.click[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

After trying so hard with bind, unbind, on, off, click, attr, removeAttr, prop I made it work. 
So, I have the following scenario: In my html i have NOT attached any inline onclick handlers.

Then in my Javascript i used the following to add an inline onclick handler:

```
$(element).attr('onclick','myFunction()');
```

To remove this at a later point from Javascript I used the following:

```
$(element).prop('onclick',null);
```

This is the way it worked for me to bind and unbind click events dinamically in Javascript. Remember NOT to insert any inline onclick handler in your elements.

Comment: Couple of issues with this, firstly you're using two different methods to set and nullify the onclick handler. What is wrong with using `.prop` for both? secondly It's not good practice to pass a "string" reference to a function as you did in your first line, as far as i'm aware this leads to a call to `eval()` which is evil! :)

Comment: @MarkWalters - in short, I think he uses attr correctly to set the onclick, and is forced to use prop to remove by IE. From the jQuery "removeattr" docs: "Note: Removing an inline onclick event handler using .removeAttr() doesn't achieve the desired effect in Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8. To avoid potential problems, use .prop() instead:"

Answer (score -2):

You could put all the code under the `.click` in a separated function

```
function headerClick(){
  if($(this).next('.section').is(':visible'))
  {
    $('.section:visible').slideUp()              
    $('.arrows:visible').attr("src","right.gif")
  }
  else
  {
    $('.section').slideUp();
    $(this).next('.section').slideToggle();
    $(this).find('.arrows').attr("src","down.gif")
  }
}
```

and then bind it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.section').hide();
    $('.header').click(headerClick);
});

$('#printVers').click(function(){
   if($('#formVersion').val() != "Print")
   {
       $('.header').unbind('click');
   }
   else
   {
       $('.header').click(headerClick);
   }
});
```

Comment: 'unbind' function unbinds only those functions that are bind using jquery 'bind' method.